# Disable subgrid expansion for selected rows of jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, javascript, subgrid

Problem: jqGrid with subgirds. I want to disable the expand/collapse functionality for some rows of the main grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found a way:

```
grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{
                afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData, rowelem) {

                    var rowData = grid.getRowData(rowid);
                    if(**Condition**){
                        $('tr#'+rowid, grid)
                         .children("td.sgcollapsed")
                         .html("")
                         .removeClass('ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed');
                    }
                }
            });
```

There was a bit of a problem. The code @Frank removed the icon, but the 'click' event was still triggered. Trying to unbind the 'click' event doesn't seem to work, probably because it is attached later on ( maybe on **gridComplete**). Anyway, I figured that the click event is attached using one of the 'ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed' classes, so if you remove them, the event won't be attached.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the gridConfig

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData, rowelem) {
    // Remove the subgrid plus button except for rows that have exceptions
    if (CONDITION) {
        $('#' + rowid).children("td.sgcollapsed").unbind().html("");
    }
},
```

Comment: As Madalin mentions, this only removes the icon.  Users can still click into it, meaning the functionality still exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to disable or hide the subgrids expand and collapse button then use this on loadcomplete,

```
jQuery("#GridTeableID").jqGrid('hideCol', "subgrid");
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no jqGrid API for this. You will have to wait until the grid is created and then, perhaps from the `loadComplete` event, you will need to manually loop over all rows and disable selected ones.

If you inspect the DOM elements that compose the grid you can probably figure out a way to remove / disable the expander for selected rows. Perhaps by using [jQuery.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).